# Slang usage of das Glück

Tags: meaning, slang

Is the word *das Glück* ever used in German to describe the euphoric state arising from the consumption of mind-altering substances?

Why do I need to know? In Russian, there is a slang word *глюк*, which sounds similar to *Glück* and means "a hallucination". Some say it has a German origin; I'm wondering if there may be any truth to that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120410/discussion-on-question-by-mustaccio-slang-usage-of-das-gluck).

Comment: Nobody can tell if *Glück* is **ever** used in that sense. Many people speak German everyday. Somebody may use it in that sense. But it is definitely not a common or popular use of the word.

Comment: o ho ho,  ha ha ha, you have not seen the complex cluster of etymologies that revolves around *Gaukler*, *juggle*, and a certain Vulgar Reconstruction. I'd call this highly uncertain, and I have no source that suggests *Glück* be related, but the given question makes it mo likely than not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have never heard of "Glück" being used in that sense. However, it is used with a similar meaning in compound words:

"Glücksgefühl" is used to describe an euphoric feeling in general. The word "Glückspillen" colloquially means antidepressants like Prozac (Fluctin in Germany). "Glückshormone" are serotonine and dopamine.

By the way, "Glückspilz" is something entirely different and has nothing to do with hallucinogenic mushrooms. Also, a "Glückskeks" is just a Chinese fortune cookie.

Comment: This answer would profit from qualified references. I wouldn't give heed to your personal opinion that "Glückspilz" is something else *entirely*

Answer (score 2):

The German word "Glück" translates in other Germanic languages like Dutch or Flemish as "Geluk" relating to the verb "gelukken" which means being conclusively successful with no reference to any particular resulting mental state. German "Glück" describes luck as well as happiness, but does not include having fun. It expresses blissful happiness, rather than euphoria. In that sense it moves away from the meaning of глюк. It wouldn't be the first time though, distinctions get translated into their opposite when crossing a language border. I personally doubt there is a connection, but with slang you never know. I've heard the word "unkaputtbar" being used in Asian advertising. I'm just saying.

Comment: German has the verb [*glücken*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/glücken) with the described Dutch meaning as well (not as a noun though).

Comment: that would be *gelingen* before Nasal Spirant though.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that "Glück" is used as a *single word* in that context. What comes closest to it is "Drogenglück". Some examples:

> [Recht auf **Drogenglück**! Gebt die Drogen frei!](https://www.heise.de/forum/Telepolis/Kommentare/Drogenpolitik-Links-bitte-nicht-zu-liberal/Recht-auf-Drogenglueck/posting-1625866/show/https://www.heise.de/forum/Telepolis/Kommentare/Drogenpolitik-Links-bitte-nicht-zu-liberal/Recht-auf-Drogenglueck/posting-1625866/show/)

> [Von der ersten Ecstasy-Erfahrung des 31jährigen über die Beschaffungskriminalität mit Diebstahl und Einbruch führt dieses Leben in die Asozialität eines Junkiedaseins und mehrfacher Haft; ein sich verhängnisvoll beschleunigender Kreislauf, bei dem sich kurzes **Drogenglück**, Gefängnis und Therapie abwechseln.](https://www.verlagshaus-roemerweg.de/Berlin_University_Press/Hermann_Wenning-Lauf_zurueck_ins_Leben-EAN:9783862800681.html)

> [... wie sich das "normale Glück" vom "**Drogenglück**" unterscheidet.](https://www.ard.de/home/themenwoche/Joerg_Boeckem___Der_Preis_fuer_Drogen_Gluecksmomente_ist_unverhaeltnismaessig_hoch_/433478/index.html)

> [Sie  befinden  sich  noch  in  diesem  sich verhängnisvoll   beschleunigenden Kreislauf, bei dem sich kurzes **Drogenglück**, Gefängnis und Therapie abwechseln.](https://www.jva-bielefeld-senne.nrw.de/behoerde/presse/Artikel_2013/2013_12_13_NW.pdf)

> [... und während Bruder, Schwester und Freund dem **Drogenglück** frönen ...](https://michaelalthen.de/texte/themenfelder/filmkritiken/weisse-rauschen-das/)